# Corona SDK - Check if object has stopped moving

Tags: coronasdk, game-engine, physics, game-physics

Hi i am making a game with Corona SDK. I have a moving ball (physical object) to monitor. I need an event when the ball stops. If i set `DrawMode` to `hybrid`, i can see the ball changes color when it stops moving. Is there any built-in event available to check if the ball is stopped moving or any other way to check? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found what i wanted. There is boolean property for each object `isAwake` which returns the awake state of object. If ball is moving it returns `true` otherwise `false`. Now i am checking this property with 1500ms of timer.
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/isAwake.html

Please reply if anyone has better solution.

Comment: Hi, how have you done this? By using another thread or is there another approach? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, there's timer method. Thank you for your question and answer it was very helpful.

Comment: Just declare variable for timer, local awakeTimer. Then use timer like this: awakeTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1500, checkAwakeTimer, 0), Then check in you function like this:
local function checkAwakeTimer( e )
  if (Ball.isAwake == false) then
   MainGame:stopCheckingBallAwake()
else
// do whatever you want
  end
 end